# Access DOM elements using Javascript in automation anywhere

Tags: javascript, rpa, automationanywhere

I would like to know how do we access an element (for ex -by classname) in JavaScript that is used with run script option in Automation anywhere for a specific website.
The normal JavaScript operation with variables work in AA **but if i try using DOM elements it gives error as Document is undefined.**
*I am trying this with JS as it is cross browser compatible and not using VBscript as it restricts only to IE.*

Please share some example that highlights my problem scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run Script runs the script under the Windows Scripting Runtime - I think thats what it is called - the AA manual for Run Script doesn't say what it uses.
To access the browsers DOM you need the script to be run in the browser. Use Web Recorder / Execute javascript function.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below bot for how to use jQuery for DOM manipulation in Automation Anywhere

https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/dom-manipulations-using-jquery/